# How to encrypt user password in Freeradius

Tags: debian, freeradius

I recently set up a freeradius server and would like to change the user password that is presently in cleartext to encrypted in the /etc/freeradius/3.0/users file.

This is what it looks like on the server.

[image]

When I authenticate on the server, I can see the username and password in the `/var/log/freeradius/radius.log` file. How can I get it encrypted? I'm using Debian.

[image]

Comment: For anyone else with the same question, I whipped up [this Perl script](https://gist.github.com/rc4/305a7f9cf945127fd045546cad4b13e5) that gives you the exact configuration line you need for a salted SHA256 password. It's a little easier than the Python one below too IMO, since it prompts for the password and generates a salt for you automatically ;-)

Answer (score 3):

In short,

1. You need to specify a password hash format instead of `Cleartext-Password`, and
2. You need to set `auth_goodpass` and `auth_badpass` to 'no' to prevent logging passwords.

### Specifying a hash format

As described in the [rlm_pap man page](https://freeradius.org/radiusd/man/rlm_pap.html), there are a number of password hash settings that can be used instead of `Cleartext-Password`.  Let us take a simple example, `MD5-Password`:

```
#bob    Cleartext-Password := "hello"
bob     MD5-Password:= "7d793037a0760186574b0282f2f435e7"
        Reply-Message := "Hello, %{User-Name}"
```

You can easily generate an md5 password hash like such:

```
$ echo -n world | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'
7d793037a0760186574b0282f2f435e7
$
```

When we test this against our server we see it authenticates:

```
$ radtest bob world localhost 1 testing123
Sent Access-Request Id 214 from 0.0.0.0:34920 to 127.0.0.1:1812 length 73
        User-Name = "bob"
        User-Password = "world"
        NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.1.1
        NAS-Port = 1
        Message-Authenticator = 0x00
        Cleartext-Password = "world"
Received Access-Accept Id 214 from 127.0.0.1:1812 to 127.0.0.1:34920 length 32
        Reply-Message = "Hello, bob"
```

You can also specify your hash with the generic `Password-With-Header` option:

```
#bob    Cleartext-Password := "hello"
bob     Password-With-Header := "{md5}7d793037a0760186574b0282f2f435e7"
        Reply-Message := "Hello, %{User-Name}"
```

This has the same effect as the `MD5-Password` version did.  The list of accepted headers is on that [rlm_pap](https://freeradius.org/radiusd/man/rlm_pap.html) man page.

One of the most interesting headers available is `Crypt-Password` because it will run password hashes through libcrypt and therefore will work with whatever hashes you find in `/etc/shadow`.  For example, on a Debian system, yescrypt hashes:

```
bob     Crypt-Password := "$y$j9T$2fOq6bdva3zoX6OfH.JvY0$PbUGbp1U.UXFAnGrkDrYnLZEDK.PXO/HXDsBn4mCsM8"
        Reply-Message := "Hello, %{User-Name}"
```

(Password in this case is `a38sgena`)

### Disabling logging of passwords

In order to disable logging of passwords, find the `auth_goodpass` and `auth_badpass` selections within the `radiusd.conf` file:

```
#  Log passwords with the authentication requests.
#  auth_badpass  - logs password if it's rejected
#  auth_goodpass - logs password if it's correct
#
#  allowed values: {no, yes}
#
auth_badpass = no
auth_goodpass = no
```

Make sure those are set to 'no' and your logging will stop including passwords.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I changed the values as stated  but i could log in via ssh from another computer with the username and  clear-text password, now i can't with  the MD5 hashed password.  How do i achieve that ?

Comment: If you're calling the PAP module after the files module it should just work.  You'd also need to make sure the RADIUS packets contain User-Password, as RADIUS CHAP authentication won't work with hashed passwords, only RADIUS PAP authentication.

Comment: How are you generating the MD5 hash?  A common mistake is to miss the `-n` argument to `echo` so that the hashed password includes a newline.  `echo -n password | md5sum` will create a working hash for 'password'

Answer (score 2):

Here is the list of attributes coresponding to the hashing method : https://freeradius.org/radiusd/man/rlm_pap.txt

```
Header          Attribute           Description
------          ---------           -----------
{clear}         Cleartext-Password  Clear-text passwords
{cleartext}     Cleartext-Password  Clear-text passwords
{crypt}         Crypt-Password      Unix-style "crypt"ed passwords
{md5}           MD5-Password        MD5 hashed passwords
{base64_md5}    MD5-Password        MD5 hashed passwords
{smd5}          SMD5-Password       MD5 hashed passwords, with a salt
{sha}           SHA-Password        SHA1 hashed passwords
                SHA1-Password       SHA1 hashed passwords
{ssha}          SSHA-Password       SHA1 hashed passwords, with a salt
{sha2}          SHA2-Password       SHA2 hashed passwords
{sha224}        SHA2-Password       SHA2 hashed passwords
{sha256}        SHA2-Password       SHA2 hashed passwords
{sha384}        SHA2-Password       SHA2 hashed passwords
{sha512}        SHA2-Password       SHA2 hashed passwords
{ssha224}       SSHA2-224-Password  SHA2 hashed passwords, with a salt
{ssha256}       SSHA2-256-Password  SHA2 hashed passwords, with a salt
{ssha384}       SSHA2-384-Password  SHA2 hashed passwords, with a salt
{ssha512}       SSHA2-512-Password  SHA2 hashed passwords, with a salt
{nt}            NT-Password         Windows NT hashed passwords
{nthash}        NT-Password         Windows NT hashed passwords
{md4}           NT-Password         Windows NT hashed passwords
{x-nthash}      NT-Password         Windows NT hashed passwords
{ns-mta-md5}    NS-MTA-MD5-Password Netscape MTA MD5 hashed passwords
{x- orcllmv}    LM-Password         Windows LANMAN hashed passwords
{X- orclntv}    NT-Password         Windows NT hashed passwords
```

Don't forget that the protocol and method you are using to authenticate your client will affect wich method of hashing you can use.

You can find a table I used to configure my Freeradius server for the protocol and password compatibility : http://deployingradius.com/documents/protocols/compatibility.html

[image: protocol and password compatibility]

To generate a sha256 salted password, I used the following script on github (you need to edit the last 2 lines to change the password and the salt) : https://gist.github.com/bestrocker221/f506eee8ccadc60cab71d5f633b7cc07

Comment: Thank you . How can i use the hash value to authenticate via ssh  using  username  bob and hash value "6afedb7a8348eb4ebdbe0c77ef92db4c"

Comment: Does authenticating using ssh work ? (with a cleartext for exemple). I never tried that, personnaly I use wpa_supplicant to send the login and password to a switch connected to my freeradius server.

Comment: Yes it does . I configured  /etc/pam.d/  on the client server  and AAA on the   catalyst switch . i can  ssh  using the user  and cleartext-password i created on the radius server. I did the same with the MD5  it didn't work .

Comment: Maybe authentication using the ssh protocol doesn't handle any encryption of the password :c

Comment: Thanks again for  the follow up . will it help if configure SSL/TLS on radius  server ? will it encrypt password in the radius.log file ?

Comment: When I configured the SSL/TLS protocol on the radius server, i generated certificates. Try PEAP-GTC, as PEAP bring TLS to the exchange of credentials. This is what i am using to authenticate with sha256 salted password